# Flask commit at once of 2 different queries in different templates

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am new to flask and I created a registration form, but it is in 2 different templates-
1st template - Manually filling all the information of the user
2nd template - upload all the documents

1st template inserting values in the user table and 2nd template inserting documents into userdoc table

My question is how to commit once, like if some user fills only 1st template and leaves the 2nd then I don't want to insert that 1st table also if the user inserted 1st and 2nd then only in both tables it should insert.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to store data across requests (besides using a database), is using the [`session`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=session#flask.session).

A solution for this is to create a boolean column `finished_registration` in your user table, and only set it to true after the submission of the second form.

This way it's easy to setup some job to automatically delete users that has not finished registration.